# Beautifulsoup: Getting a new line when I tried to access the soup.head.next_sibling value with Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying an example from the BeautifulSoup[Docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and found it acting weird. When I try to access the next_sibling value, instead of the "body" a '\n' is coming in to picture.

```
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>

<p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
<a href="http://example.com/elsie" class="sister" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
<a href="http://example.com/lacie" class="sister" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
<a href="http://example.com/tillie" class="sister" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
soup.head.next_sibling
u'\n'
```

I am using latest version of beautifulSoup4. i.e 4.3.2. Please help me out. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 [kinds of objects](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-objects) that `BeautifulSoup` "sees" in the HTML:

- `Tag`
- `NavigableString`
- `Comment`

When you get `.next_sibling` it returns you the next object after the current which, in your case, is a text node (`NavigableString`). Explained in the documentation [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling).

If you want to find the next `Tag` after the current, use [`find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling), or, with specifying the tag name: `find_next_sibling("body")`.

You can also use the "next sibling" [CSS Selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("head + *")
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe for that detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
soup.head.find_next_sibling()
```

or

```
soup.head.next_sibling.next_sibling
```